# How to restore Windows Bare Metal Image to VM

Tags: windows, virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi, backup-restoration

Trust all are well.  I am trying to restore my Physical Server to a VM using the Windows BMR image and this is where I keep getting the error saying that my VM disk is too small.

Is there a workaround for this?

I have been using Windows backup on my server.  My server is Windows 2012R2. A DC with SQL SRV Running for Proprietary SW.

I need to be able to restore the server to VM.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the same number and size of disks for the image to restore onto.  If you have, then try making the VMs disk(s) slightly larger than the disk(s) in the image.

Additionally you may want to take a look at this other SF question: [How do I restore a Windows Server 2008 R2 bare metal backup to a Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V instance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/549231/how-do-i-restore-a-windows-server-2008-r2-bare-metal-backup-to-a-windows-server?rq=1) for an alternative way to P2V your server.